# Django AJAX looping data

Tags: django

In my view I'm trying to loop all pages and extract the name for each using the code below. But it does not appear to work.

How can I achieve this?

**view.py**

```
 json_dict = json.loads(request.POST['site'])


  for item in json_dict['pages']:

            item.json_dict['name']
```

**the JSON data**

```
{
    "someitem": "xaAX",
    "pages": [
        {
            "id": "1364484811734",
            "name": "Page Name",
            "type": "basic",
            "components": {
                "img": "",
                "text": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "1364484812918",
            "name": "Contact",
            "type": "contact",
            "components": {
                "text": "Send us an email using the form below.",
                "contact-form": {
                    "contact-name": "zzz",
                    "contact-email": "zz"
                }
            }
        },

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
json_dict = json.loads(request.POST['site'])

for item in json_dict['pages']:
    print item['name']
```